# Selecting MIN value from two tables and putting them in the same table

Tags: sql, database, datatables

I have don't have a lot of experiance with SQLs. I have two tables with prices from to different comanpies. I want to select the MIN price from each company and put them in a table together.

```
|Company   |Start city| Stop city| Price    | 
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | 
| A        | HONGKONG | OSLO     | 250      | 
| A        | BANGKOK  | OSLO     | 400      | 
| A        | BANGKOK  | OSLO     | 300      | 
| A        | HONGKOMG | OSLO     | 500      | 


|Company   |Start city| Stop city| Price    | 
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | 
| B        | HONGKONG | OSLO     | 500      | 
| B        | BANGKOK  | OSLO     | 100      | 
| B        | BANGKOK  | OSLO     | 600      | 
| B        | HONGKOMG | OSLO     | 150      |
```

The outcome I need it if select BANGKOK - OSLO, I get the MIN value of price from each table:

```
|Company   |Start city| Stop city| Price    | 
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | 
| A        | BANGKOK  | OSLO     | 300      | 
| B        | BANGKOK  | OSLO     | 100      |
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? What have you tried so far? Please show us your efforts and explain where you got stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good way to approach this is to work with a [database view](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(SQL)).

This view contains all the cheapest offers collected from multiple tables

```sql
CREATE VIEW cheapest_offers (company, start_city, stop_city, price) AS (
SELECT company,
       start_city,
       stop_city,
       MIN(price) as price
  FROM (SELECT * FROM t1 
       UNION SELECT * FROM t2) sub
 GROUP BY company, start_city, stop_city
);
```

*Or use the CTE suggestion that @trillion made*

You can then query this view like a normal table:

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM cheapest_offers
 WHERE start_city = 'BANGKOK' AND stop_city = 'OSLO'
```

See https://dbfiddle.uk/MK5Q1ec8 for a working version

Comment: Thanks, it worked!! Now i know about views :)

Comment: Which method do you think is better? I want to desplay the minimums in Excel.

Comment: A view lives in the database, so if you plan to consistently use it( for example in an application or to generate statistics ) I would say go with the view. If it's just a one time thing, just query it.

Answer (score 2):

- first combine two tables using the union all - make sure you have the same number of columns and in the same order just like you are showing in the example
- then for a given company, for a given start and stop city you are finding the minimum value of the price
- later you can create queries to check for specific case

```
with main as (

select * from table1
union all
select * from table2
),finding_min as (
select 
company,
start_city,
stop_city,
min(price) as minimum_price
from main
group by 1,2,3
)
select * from finding_min
where start_city = 'BANGKOK' and stop_city = 'OSLO'
```

Comment: Could get this method to work, but thanks for answering :)

Comment: @abh what error are you getting ?

Comment: I tried it again now, and it worked! I think I had a syntax error when i first tried it. Sorry about that :) Do you think this or the view method is better?  I want to desplay the minimums in Excel

Comment: a view needs to be updated if you change something in the schema and might break things, if you are not doing something complicated just go with the query instead of a view